# GORM Gen, retrieve the last record in each group

Tags: go, orm, go-gorm

For example I have such a model:

```sql
create table users {
    created_at  datetime(3)  
    status      str                                                                           
    username    longtex
}
```

I need to get the last created value for some_value for each of the usernames and specific status.
In raw sql it's something like this:

```sql
SELECT users.*
FROM users INNER JOIN (
    SELECT username, MAX(created_at) as latest
    WHERE status == "accepted"
    FROM users GROUP BY username) gusers
ON users.username = gusers.username
AND users.created_at = gusers.latest
```

How do I do this using GORM Gen?

I tried something like this:

```golang
q := query.Use(d.db)
u := q.User
lau := u.As("last_accepted_users")

lauCreatedAtMax := lau.CreatedAt.Max().As("max_date")
all, err := u.WithContext(ctx).
    Join(lau.WithContext(ctx).
        Select(lau.Username, lauCreatedAtMax).
        Where(lau.Status.Eq(model.FormStatusAccepted)).
        Group(lau.Username),
        u.Username.EqCol(lau.Username),
        u.CreatedAt.EqCol(lauCreatedAtMax),
    ).Find()
```

But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I did it with a code like that:

```golang
q := query.Use(d.db)
u := q.User
u2 := u.As("u2")
subQuery := u.WithContext(ctx).
  Where(u.Status.Eq(model.FormStatusAccepted)).
  Group(u.Username).
  Select(u.Username, u.CreatedAt.Max().As("created_at_max")).
  As("u2")

users, err := u.WithContext(ctx).
  LeftJoin(subQuery, u2.Username.EqCol(u.Username)).
  Where(field.NewInt64("u2", "created_at_max").EqCol(u.CreatedAt)).
  Find()
```